# Possible to create aliases in GIT?

Tags: git, alias

In bash I can create an alias like this:

```
alias ls="ls -h"
```

This changes the command `ls -l` from running like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 joe bob        0 Mar 25 12:06 4.7
drwxr-xr-x    1 joe bob     4096 Mar 25 14:58 Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Installer
-rw-r--r--    1 joe bob       92 Mar 20 12:41 Automation-Timer
```

To running like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 joe bob        0 Mar 25 12:06 4.7
drwxr-xr-x    1 joe bob     4.0k Mar 25 14:58 Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Installer
-rw-r--r--    1 joe bob       92 Mar 20 12:41 Automation-Timer
```

Note how the units are shown in the second example.

---

Is it possible to do this with git commands?

Whenever I interactively run a `git log`, I would like it to be aliased to `git log --relative-date`.  Is this possible?

I know that I can create a new git command to do this however, I am not especially interested in doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want to have `git log` always use --relative-date without having to pass the flag - and you dont want to have to use a command other than `git log` itself.

The answer is yes, and this is done through the config files.

```
git config --global log.date 'relative'
```

From now on any time you call `git log` it will use relative dates.

To see a complete list of all the configurable options, take a look at [the man page for git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

Thanks to @Saaman for the link

Comment: Huh, that is a great answer.  How did you find that or what did you search for?  Is there a list of all 'global' things that you can set on log?

Comment: You can find a complete list of variables there : https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html. All these variables can be set globally, or per-user, or for only one repository.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Does that fully answer your question, I was unsure if you were also trying to do something in git wil `ls` or if you were just using it as example of using an alias to modify a command.

Comment: My gitconfig file has a few handy aliases: https://github.com/none-da/dotfiles/blob/master/dotgitconfig#L6

Comment: Am I correct in believing that there is no way to enable the `--graph` option using the configuration options?

Comment: I think you are correct. To do that you either need to just make a git alias with a slightly different name, or do it in bash like Shawn explained.

Answer (score 2):

Shell aliases cannot include spaces (on the left hand side) and you can't use git alias, but you could create a shell function instead.

```sh
git ()
{
  if [[ $1 = log ]]
  then
    shift
    /bin/git log --relative-date "$@"
  else
    /bin/git "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: +1 That is a good way to do it through the bash shell.  A bit on the unmaintainable side but good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround I have found to do this is to do something like this in the .bashrc

```
alias gitl='git log --relative-date'
```

It is then still possible to run it like this:

```
gitl --graph
```

Which would be expanded to something like this:

```
git log --relative-date --graph
```